# Graph is drawn in extra figure, not in subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I practiced some plotting methods in python and there was a problem when I used subplot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 8))
sns.barplot('A', 'B', data=data, ax=ax[0])
sns.factorplot('A', 'B', data=data, ax=ax[1])
plt.close(2)
plt.show()
```

The code that I used is above. I expected that this results a subplot in two graphs (barplot on left and factorplot on right), but it doesn't.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0nBl.png)

The factorplot has gone and I could know that this plot was in the newly-generated figure and closed due to `plt.close(2)`. I want to control the factorplot's index but it seems it doesn't work. Any tips for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

`seaborn.catplot` (the new API to `seaborn.factorplot`) is a figure level plot to be used on facet grids, [see here for details](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html). Thus the `ax` parameter is **not allowed** with `catplot`. Seaborn should print the following warning when passing an `ax` to `catplot`:

> some_path_to_lib\seaborn\categorical.py:3762: UserWarning: catplot is a figure-level function and does not accept target axes. You may wish to try stripplot
> warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)

To get your desired plot, use `stripplot` instead:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 2), columns=['A', 'B'])

f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 8))
sns.barplot('A', 'B', data=data, ax=ax[0])
sns.stripplot('A', 'B', data=data, ax=ax[1])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks @JE_Muc, I checked the reference and it seems that `pointplot` is more similar with `factorplot` than `stripplot`. I appreciate your tip!

Comment: @Ben You are welcome and may also upvote/accept my answer if it helped you. :)